# Why doesn't a sub-expression with < get evaluated first in my Boolean expression?

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence, boolean-expression

The reference I'm using for Ruby operators is http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4 According to this reference, and others I've seen, equality operators take precedence over logical AND (`&&`, not Ruby's `and`).

I have the following:

```
foo = nil
foo < 5 # NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

To check for `foo` we do:

```
foo && (foo < 5) # Note the parenthesis
```

But this works:

```
foo && foo < 5 # why does this work?
```

Because of operator precedence, `foo < 5` should happen first, resulting in an error before the AND can even be evaluated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Short answer: Evaluation happens *after* tokenizing. Longer explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

`<` has higher precedence than `&&`, which affects how [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) tokenizes your expressions. Evaluation happens *after* tokenizing.

### Booleans and S-Expressions

In your example, `foo && foo < 5` is tokenized into two expressions:

```rb
require 'ripper'
Ripper.sexp 'foo && foo < 5'
#=> [:program,
# [[:binary,
#   [:vcall, [:@ident, "foo", [1, 0]]],
#   :"&&",
#   [:binary, [:vcall, [:@ident, "foo", [1, 7]]], :<, [:@int, "5", [1, 13]]]]]]
```

So, the parser sees this as functionally equivalent to `(foo) && (foo < 5)` because `<` has higher precedence than `&&`. However, since Ruby uses short-circuit evaluation for Boolean operations, it never *evaluates* the right-hand side of your Boolean expression unless `foo` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for great answer and for curating my question!

Answer (score 1):

The following helped me a bit to understand the issue:

I can rewrite

```
foo && foo < 5
```

as

```
foo && foo.<(5)
```

Which now makes much more sense. You would expect the same behavior from a statement like:

```
foo && foo.even?
```

You would expect first `foo` to be evaluated and only then `foo.even?`. The same is here when `foo` gets evaluated before `foo.<(5)` or as you can write it `foo < 5`.

Now I'm trying to come up with an example where `&&` and `<` really behave according to the precedence table, but still without success.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand it a bit better. Like you said and example where they really  behave according to the precedence table would be great!

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` evaluate operators from left to right. and the evaluation stops as soon as the truth or falsity of the statement is known. `foo < 5` will never get evaluated. This is why the second approach works.

Also, `&&` and `||` have much higher precedence. They are NOT the same as `and` and `or`.

Comment: I'm still not totally convinced... On the reference I linked `&&` has lower precedence than `<`. So even if `&&` stops at the first sign of a false, the `<` should be evaluated first.

Comment: maybe this http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/ helps. && and || in ruby are a little different than in other languages.

Comment: Good article in general, but it addresses what `or` and `and` do, which is not what we're talking about.

Comment: which version of ruby are you using? I just tried the code in irb on my comp:                                                        hrishi>irb
    irb(main):001:0> foo = nil
    => nil
    irb(main):002:0> foo < 5
    NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):2
 from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
    irb(main):003:0> foo && (foo < 5)
    => nil
    irb(main):004:0> foo && foo < 5
    => nil
    irb(main):005:0>

Comment: Strange, I'm using 2.0.0p0

Comment: my ruby version is : ruby 1.9.3p0. Strange indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The precedence is about binding, not necessarily order of operations.  If the LHS of the `&&` evaluates to false then it won't bother evaluating the RHS at all.

Ruby is intended to be kind of functional, so I'll give you some Haskell to show this in more detail:

```
true && x = x
false && x = false
```

Since the left hand side is false, it will never go on to calculate the right hand side, so it will crash.  This is some very simply lazy evaluation.  On the second line, the value of `x` is irrelevant, so it never bothers calculating it as it doesn't need to.  This is the beauty of lazy evaluation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` short circuits, if `foo` is `nil` or `false`, the right hand side will not be evaluated.

The parser of course will do what it will do as described below.  But the evaluation happens after that step.

Using `parser`gem to examine the code, we can get some hints as to what the Ruby parser is doing.

I have these two files:

foo1.rb

```
foo = nil
foo && foo < 5
```

The AST representation:

```
(begin
  (lvasgn :foo
    (nil))
  (and
    (lvar :foo)
    (send
      (lvar :foo) :<
      (int 5))))
```

foo2.rb

```
foo = nil
foo && (foo < 5)
```

The AST representation:

```
(begin
  (lvasgn :foo
    (nil))
  (and
    (lvar :foo)
    (begin
      (send
        (lvar :foo) :<
        (int 5)))))
```

I don't know if that clarifies or confuses.